# Keep MySQL data inside Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I use Docker and Docker Compose on a project. I hava 3 containers : PHP, MySQL and Nginx.
For now, MySQL binary data is stored inside the MySQL container (`/var/lib/mysql/...`).

I think this is not a best practice and may even be dangerous if the container is rebuild from scratch.

What is the best way to keep data safe?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is quite simple, with Docker Compose :

```
version: "2.0"


services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
            - "mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql" # data container
volumes:
    mysql_data:
        driver: local
```

And I can see my volume with Docker

```
docker volume ls
```

Comment: docker-compose is also a great way (more elegant) to accomplish this, good suggestion. upvoted

Answer (score 1):

If this is a standalone server, the best way to keep your data safe would be to use `docker data volumes`. The two options are:

> **Data Volume**: A data volume is a specially-designated directory within one or more containers that bypasses the Union File System.

The data volumes can be created automatically by docker on the filesystem like:

```
docker run -d --name nginx -v /usr/share/nginx/html nginx

docker inspect nginx
...
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Name": "4fead165b4c3ba1a900ca1ab0e095f43ee32d6a4c61eba37f4bcb28c58ce7036",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/4fead165b4c3ba1a900ca1ab0e095f43ee32d6a4c61eba37f4bcb28c58ce7036/_data",
                "Destination": "/usr/share/nginx/html",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
...
```

Or you can mount a filsystem path on the server of your choosing to the docker container like:

```
docker run -d --name nginx2 -v /tmp/test:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
```

for more information, see:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/